# Correctly outputting new assignments during each loop of a for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want a new answer to be output every iteration of this `for` loop. Currently it is update the `fluence` to be just the last last loop output.

```
for i = 1:nx
    fluence= data1cm(i).data(:,3).*25000000.*(energygap);
    %dim=size(c)
    %'fluence' num2str((i)+1)= fluence;
end
```

Comment: It depends on what `data1cm(i).data` and `energygap` are. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you index into `data1cm(i)` you can save the value into `fluence` in the same manner, e.g. if the result of `data1cm(i).data(:,3).*25000000.*(energygap)` is scalar you can do

```
for i = 1:nx
    fluence(i)= data1cm(i).data(:,3).*25000000.*(energygap);
end
```

Then `fluence` will be a 1*nx array of all the results.

For efficiency one should always initialise the variable, that is create it with some temporary values and then overwrite these values.

```
fluence = zeros(1,nx);
for i = 1:nx
    fluence(i)= data1cm(i).data(:,3).*25000000.*(energygap);
end
```

Here I initialise `fluence` with zeros, and then all of these zeros are overwritten by the result of `data1cm(i).data(:,3).*25000000.*(energygap);`. Other initialisations are e.g. `ones` and `nan`.